# Deny access to directory in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

is there a way to deny access to the directory in NextJS? For example, if I want to forbid access to directory /public/images ?

Than I would server images via api routes, so image will look like this in component:

```
<Image src="/api/image1" alt="Logo" width={720} height={160} />
```

And image1 api route:

```
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpg');
  const imageBuffer2 = await (await fetch('http://example.com/images/logo.jpg')).body;
  res.send(imageBuffer2)
```

But users will not be able to access the image by typing `"example.com/images/logo.jpg"` in the browser.

My goal is to serve the image only for the user, who is logged in. In PHP is a similar task quite easy, but how to achieve this in NextJS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't definitely tell `no`, but I tried to find some info about a similar question. Actually, you can't access from `URL` to any folder except `/pages`, for example, `/public` folder. (you can test by yourself).

In `/pages` you can't deny access to a page, but you can do some verification on the page you like to deny access.

Example:

1. You like to deny access to /pages/adminInfo.tsx
2. You do some verification before page renders, for example, in `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`, for example, `user` has role `"admin"`.
3. If `user` has no role, you can `router.push("/404.js")` and redirect `user` with no access to "Page not found" page (or any other page)
4. For the api routes, you do the same condition as for the page. (if condition before triggering the page)

P.S. You can create a component (which verifies conditions you need) and add it to "secure pages" - like this you will secure some info

So, for the images, you can simply `if` to check if user is loaded and "upload" the image to page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if pure NextJS is achievable or not, however, we use NextJS with express, as following example, I protect any file inside `protected` folder, so in your case, you check user authentication before sending request

```js
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");
const app = next({dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const server = express();
app.prepare().then(()=>{
  server.get('/protected/*', (req, res) => {
    // write your protection logic here
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthenticated');
  })
  server.get("*", (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });
  server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`listening to port 3000`);
  });
})
```