# How to enable users to download zip file inside a folder using Next JS

Tags: next.js

In NextJS application, I have a zip files inside download folder in root directory, not in the public folder.

How to enable users (later only for paid users) to download the zip file from client?

Comment: maybe this can help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68999179/deny-access-to-directory-in-nextjs

Comment: You need to handle your zip file on the sever and send to client via post request. Use adm-zip npm on the server. And downloadjs on client side.